# How do i load admin/language/english/english.php file using open cart?

Tags: opencart

How do i load admin/language/english/english.php file using open cart? I'm not getting any error about that file but it is not load in my site.

Answer (score 0):

The main language file will load automatically when your sub-language file is loaded. For example, if you load `/catalog/language/english/account/account.php` then the `/catalog/language/english/english.php` file is loaded first, then the account strings are loaded on top of these, overwriting any with a duplicate key value

Comment: you are right but content of english.php is not called in any file.

Comment: It is - `/system/library/language.php`